# sed whole string replacement not working

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression, getopts

I have two scripts `ins.sh` and `variable.sh`. `variables.sh` holds various key-value pairs.

ins.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e # Exit upon error

# This script generates a 64-bit system
source variables.sh

# Parse options
while getopts ":t:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        t )
            if [ $OPTARG = TRUE ] || [ $OPTARG = FALSE ]; then
                sed -i "s/*.MAKE_TESTS=.*/MAKE_TESTS=${OPTARG}/" variables.sh
            else
                echo "Invalid argument. -t only takes either 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'."
                exit 1
            fi
            ;;

        \? )
            echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
            ;;

        : )
            echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument."
            ;;
    esac
done
```

variables.sh

```
MAKE_TESTS=TRUE
MAKE_PARALLEL=-j4
INSTALL_DIR=/tmp/install-dir
```

To change the value is issue the following command:

```
bash ins.sh -t FALSE
```

This command should change to the `MAKE_TESTS=FALSE` but this doesn't happens at all.

I just want to toggle the values from `TRUE` to `FALSE` and vice versa. To achieve this, I was replacing the whole string and passing the value provided by the user.

**UPDATE**

For the time being, I've found a way to accomplish my task. First, I'm deleting the whole string and then adding the new string.

```
sed -i "/MAKE_TESTS/d" variables.sh
echo "MAKE_TESTS=${OPTARG}" >> variables.sh
```

**But I would still like to know why my string replacement ain't working.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
 sed -i "s/*.MAKE_TESTS=.*/MAKE_TESTS=${OPTARG}/" variables.sh
```

with:

```
 sed -i "s/.*MAKE_TESTS=.*/MAKE_TESTS=${OPTARG}/" variables.sh
```

`.*` means zero or more of any character.  By contrast, the meaning of `*.` may likely vary from one implementation of sed to another.  In GNU sed, it means a literal star, `*`, followed by any one character.  Observe:

```
$ echo 'aa' | sed 's/*./HI/'
aa
$ echo '*a' | sed 's/*./HI/'
HI
```